# Spring MVC resource TAG in MVC configuration

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, resources

I'm trying to find a clean solution to configure spring mvc to handle requests to static resources using the tag resources in my configuration. 
It works well so far for simple configuration like:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="file:${environment_variable}/mystaticfolder/img/" cache-period="31556926" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="file:${environment_variable}/mystaticfolder/css/" cache-period="31556926" />
```

and so on..

But i would like to be able to redirect the requests coming with a path containing "content" (always static files)+ specific_folder with some kind of regular expression (like rewrite rules).

For example:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/content/${specificfolder}**" 
location="file:${environment_variable}/content/${specificfolder}/" cache-period="31556926" />
```

Without doing a configuration for each folder under content.
Is that possible ?.
I could not find some detail about what i can put in the "location" attribute of the tag (a link could be useful too)

Thanks in advance for any tips you can share.

Regards.
S.